# Map to study $K(n)$-local Picard Group

Tags: homotopy-theory, picard-group, chromatic-homotopy

Let $R$ be an $E_{\infty}$-ring. There's a fiber/cofiber sequence $S$: $gl_1 R \to \text{Pic}(R) \to H(\text{Pic}(R))$, where $\text{Pic}(R) =\pi_0 \text{Pic}(R)$ is the Picard group of $R$. Rotating this triangle over, we have a fiber/cofiber sequence $H(\text{Pic}(R)) \to gl_1 R \to S^{-1} \text{Pic}(R)$.

$K(n)$-localizing, we get an equivalence $L_{K(n)} gl_1 R \to L_{K(n)} S^{-1} \text{Pic}(R)$, so there is an "extension" of the Rezk logarithm to a map $S^{-1} \text{Pic}(R) \to L_{K(n)} S^{-1} \text{Pic}(R) -equiv\to L_{K(n)} gl_1 R \to L_{K(n)} R$. If $R$ is $K(n)$-local, we get, on $\pi_{-1}$, a map $\text{Pic}(R) \to \pi_{-1} R$.

What's this about? Can we write down a formula for this map? Can we use this to study the $K(n)$-local Picard group? (Some variant of it, obviously, because $\pi_{-1} E = 0$.)

Comment: See Proposition 4.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.5851.pdf or Proposition 1.10 of https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Clausen-Artin.pdf